# What to do with blowout Krausen/wort

Tags: fermentation, wort, krausen, blow-off

Surprised I couldn't find an answer to this so I'm posting the question.

I brewed my first imperial stout. Fermentation was super happy, krausen went wild and my airlock blew out (from what I'm seeing online - surprise surprise). I installed a blowout tube and everything is going well - my question is what do I do with the extra wort/krausen that's building up in my blowout container?

Do I just dump it down the drain or can I add it back to the fermenter when everything has calmed down a little (i.e. secondary fermentation has started)? I don't like the idea of wasting any of my hard work. I'm a real waste-not-want-not kinda guy.

Note that I used boiling water rather than sanitiser for my blow-off container so I'm not worried about adding sanitiser to my brew.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dump it out. Pouring blowoff back in to save yourself a pint of beer risks the entire batch for infection. In the future you can use a bigger container for primary fermentation- but even so, blowoffs can happen. Be happy you've got a healthy fermentation!

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. So it's possible but not worth the risk. Maybe I can save it to pour over ice cream. It is pretty tasty...